# SharePoint 2013 APIs for anonymous and/or mobile access

Tags: 2013, rest, client-object-model

In SharePoint 2013 (Preview), does any of the APIs (csom, REST, etc.) work with anonymous access? With mobile access?

I haven't found any reference to this in the documentation. I did a quick test that seems to show that REST works for anonymous and mobile, but this sounds too good to be true... Thanks for any information you can share!

Comment: csom does work with anonymous access but REST api ('_api') doesn't for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out eventually. It's a web app settings. Go to the Central Administration -> Manage web applications. Select your web app, click "Authentication Providers" in the ribbon", click the "Default" zone, disable "Require Use Remote Interfaces Permission".

Comment: Is this something that could also apply to Office 365?

Comment: This is not working for me :( I am stuck with issue for more than a week. can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

My experiences have been the opposite, it was easy to make the client object model available for anonymous access in 2010, but as far as I can tell it is not possible in 2013. The REST API ("/_api" and "/_vti_bin/client.svc") doesn't work with anonymous access in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

REST api does work with SharePoint 2013 with both 'Limited-access user permission lockdown mode' and 'Require Use Remote Interfaces permission' disabled.