# Sharepoint Service access from android applciation

Tags: rest, web-services

as new to share point 2013, I wod like to ask few things to et myself ready for development.

From my android application, what are the ways to to call services to add/update/delete items in list? till now i have tried share point rest services and for that i have to pass user id and password in ordewr to work. What if i dont want this way? Is there any other way ?

I need other options too like any other way for achieving this.

Share your experience and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint Online? Do you need to authenticate as a user, or is it sufficient to authenticate as an app?

Comment: No, this is not for sharepoint online and yes it is sufficient to authenticate as an app but is it possible to Post/Get the data without authentication through Rest API to/from Sharepoint list. If Yes, then please do share. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rely on [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/50297/627) and say that anonymous access to the API can be very difficult. But setting up an app is easy, you don't even need an app, all you need is to register it to get the ID and secret key.

See this link for an example:
http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/11/call-sharepoint-online-csom-from-an-external-application/

This is the basic procedure:

1. Go to **/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx** and register your app.  For URL and callback I usually use bogus data (say localhost), as in your case you want app authentication, not user authentication. Take note of Client Id and Client Secret, these are important.
2. Then go to **/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx** and set the permissions. These give you App policy permission, on a whole site collection:

   `<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
     <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
   </AppPermissionRequests>`
3. Go to **/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx** and take not of the realm, it is the last part after **@**, on the app you registered.

Now you are ready to develop.
I believe you can use this library to authenticate: https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt